# IF Statement for First Name Personalization when using a LOOKUP

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, ampscript, email-studio

I'd like to add in an `IF` statement for when first_name is blank. My sending DE does not contain first_name so I am pulling it from the master DE. This is what I have so far and it's working:

```
%%=Lookup('master','first_name','email',email)=%%
```

Where would I enter the `IF` statement to pull in the default value if `first_name` is blank?

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to set the first name as a variable and then wrap it in an `IF` statement.

```
%%[
set @firstName = Lookup('master','first_name','email',emailaddr)

IF @firstName == "" THEN
   set @firstName = "Customer"
ENDIF
]%%
Dear %%=v(@firstName)=%%
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

You can also do an inline-if ([**iif**](https://ampscript.guide/iif)) with the [**empty**](https://ampscript.guide/empty) function.  It's a little shorter.

```
%%[

set @firstName = Lookup('master','first_name','email', emailaddr)

]%%
Dear %%=iif(empty(@firstName),"Customer", @firstName)=%%,
```

Comment: This works too. A simplified `IF` statement might be more difficult to comprehend for a novice.